# data is not fetching by using ajax with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please bear me i don't how to explain my problem and i am new with mod re_writing i have two pages

1. index.php
2. search.php

index.php has a search field and a div where data would be fetch.and search field uses a Ajax to give instant result from data base.

as

[image: search field with instant results]

search field with instant results

when i am on index.php its give me proper results and here i am using a rewrite rule which turns

```
http://localhost/user_profiles/index?u=tol
```

into

```
http://localhost/user_profiles/index/u/tol
```

and give me profile view as

[image: profile view]

both url give me proper result but problem is with ajax that when im on

```
http://localhost/user_profiles/index?u=tol
```

ajax works perfectly and give me proper result but when i am on

```
    http://localhost/user_profiles/index/u/tol
```

it gives weird result as
[image: weird result]

i cant figure how to fix it here is my re_write rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule u/(.*) index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

another rule for index.php to just index

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and my ajax query is

```
maq.open('GET','search?q='+userVal,true);
```

please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that file references are relative in JavaScript.

When you're on the re-written page, you'll need to update the link to `search` by using:

```
maq.open('GET', '../../search?q='+userVal, true);
```

Essentially, two directories up from the virtual directory we're in (i.e. from `user_profiles/index/u/tol/search` to `user_profiles/index/search`).

Alternatively, you can specify it relative to the root using a leading `/`, for example:

```
maq.open('GET', '/user_profiles/index/search?q='+userVal, true);
```

Comment: now searching only working on http://localhost/user_profiles/index/u/tol but is not working on for http://localhost/user_profiles/index ??